# Call grails 3 domain in groovy script

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a groovy script, created with grails create-script.
How can I import domain class from my grails app, like

```
dep p = new User(name: 'Karl')
p.save()
```

If I try this I get unable to resolve class User.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your domain classes are in a package, just like any other Groovy class. So if your script is not in the same package, you'll need to "import" the package the domain class is in.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning but i have a Import

Comment: how are you running the script?

Comment: with "grails my-script"

Comment: How are you calling your script?